# Scan a stream of objects and add a property with the running sum in RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Assuming I have a source stream of objects as follows:

```
source$ = from([{ id: 1, cost: 10},{ id: 2, cost: 5},{ id: 3, cost: 3},{ id: 4, cost: 10}])
```

In the derived observable I would like maintain an additional property with a running sum of the cost

```
// Expected derived stream
{ id: 1, cost: 10, totalCost: 10}
{ id: 2, cost: 5,  totalCost: 15}
{ id: 3, cost: 3,  totalCost: 18}
{ id: 4, cost: 10, totalCost: 28}
```

How could it be achieved with rxjs?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find this solution:

```
import { from } from "rxjs";
import {scan} from "rxjs/internal/operators";

let source$ = from([{ id: 1, cost: 10},{ id: 2, cost: 5},{ id: 3, cost: 3},{ id: 4, cost: 10}]);


source$
.pipe(
  scan((acc,curr) => {
      return {...curr, totalCost: acc.totalCost + curr.cost}
  }, {totalCost:0})
) 
.subscribe(console.log)
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/rxjs-playground-forked-3bdpd